# Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?

Tags: html, css, input, numbers

Is there a consistent way across browsers to hide the new spin boxes that some browsers (such as Chrome) render for HTML input of type number?  I am looking for a CSS or JavaScript method to prevent the up/down arrows from appearing.

```html
<input id="test" type="number">
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using?  A screenshot would be great as well so we know what you're looking at. I'm looking at `<input type="number" min="4" max="8" />` in Chrome and seeing a typical input field with up and down arrows on the side.

Comment: You are seeing exactly what I am seeing.  I am trying to keep the type=number markup to ensure that mobile browsers bring up an appropriate keyboard, and prevent the up and down arrows from appearing in computer browsers.

Comment: If you're using number inputs, be sure to use something that plays nice with modern iOS, Android, and Desktop browsers: `<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">`. 

More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31619311/806956

Comment: What I suggest doing is writing markup along the lines of `<input type="text" placeholder="number (digits only)" pattern="[0-9]+" class="validate number-validation" ... > ` and using [jQuery Validati](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Flexible-HTML5-Form-Field-Validation-Plugin-With-jQuery-Validati.html) or similar to handle validation. I haven't tested this approach, which is why this is a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: You might be misusing that input type, the HTML spec explains that it is “not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number.” https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate. There are other attributes to control touch screen keyboards like `inputmode`.

Answer (score 1477, accepted):

This CSS effectively hides the spin-button for webkit browsers (have tested it in Chrome 7.0.517.44 and Safari Version 5.0.2 (6533.18.5)):

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```

You can always use the inspector (webkit, possibly Firebug for Firefox) to look for matched CSS properties for the elements you are interested in, look for Pseudo elements. This image shows results for an input element type="number":

[image: Inspector for input type=number (Chrome)]

Comment: It seems that Chrome no longer has a problem, so you can just use               `display: none;` as the only thing inside the selector

Comment: This is unfortunately not cross-browser so I'd advise against using `type=number` if you have to hide these arrows. E.g. currently they'd be still displayed in Opera and they'll start being displayed in Firefox, IE etc. when they implement this input type.

Comment: Just use `<input inputmode="numeric" ... /> It has [wide support now](https://caniuse.com/?search=inputmode)

Comment: I would not call that "wide support"...

Comment: for some reason I can type in the letter 'e' in Chrome 94

Comment: @Johansrk because letter 'e' can be a part of a valid number, i.e. 1e3 === 1000.

Comment: In 2022 it's ok to omit `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes because all wide-spread browsers suport the property. See details on https://caniuse.com/?search=Appearance

Comment: Can't reproduce on stackoverflow but for me this on Chrome breaks text-align making it to a wider width then it actually is. Using only display: none; in the first rule works flawlessly.

Answer (score 492):

Firefox 29 currently adds support for number elements, so here's a snippet for hiding the spinners in webkit and moz based browsers:

```css
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="number">
```

Answer (score 433):

### Short answer:

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

### Longer answer:

To add to existing answer...

### Firefox:

In current versions of Firefox, the (user agent) default value of the [`-moz-appearance` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) on these elements is `number-input`. Changing that to the value `textfield` effectively removes the spinner.

```
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

In some cases, you may want the spinner to be hidden *initially*, and then appear on hover/focus. (This is currently the default behavior in Chrome). If so, you can use the following:

```css
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="number"]:hover,
input[type="number"]:focus {
    -moz-appearance: number-input;
}
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

---

### Chrome:

In current versions of Chrome, the (user agent) default value of the [`-webkit-appearance` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) on these elements is already `textfield`. In order to remove the spinner, the `-webkit-appearance` property's value needs to be changed to `none` on the `::-webkit-outer-spin-button`/`::-webkit-inner-spin-button` pseudo classes (it is `-webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button` by default).

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

It's worth pointing out that `margin: 0` is used to remove the margin in *older* versions of Chrome.

Currently, as of writing this, here is the default user agent styling on the 'inner-spin-button' pseudo class:

```
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    align-self: stretch;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only;
}
```

Comment: i like this answer better because it includes relevant firefox info, which, when developing something, needs to be considered. webkit-only answers that ignore other browser engines leave much to be desired

Comment: It's difficult to follow "current" and "as of writing" with all the edits. Maybe revise to reference browser versions or add actual dates.

Answer (score 140):

According to [Apple’s user experience coding guide for mobile Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008248-CH1-SUBSECTION11), you can use the following to display a numeric keyboard in the iPhone browser:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

A `pattern` of `\d*` will also work.

Comment: This currently does nothing on Android, in all browsers. Tested on [this test page](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/T2VRE/show/) in Browser 4.2.2, Chrome 28, and Firefox 23 on Android 4.2. Those browsers just show the standard text keyboard with this markup.

Comment: The above comment is obsolete, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode) the most popular Android browsers support it now. Plus, even if it doesn’t do anything YET, it’s standard compliant and should be added, because browsers keep evolving

Comment: You will loose numeric validation provided by min and max as well.

Comment: How about decimals? Scientific format, negative values, international formatting? Now the dev has to write regexes for all those possibilities?

Answer (score 103):

I found a super simple solution using

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" />
```

This is supported in most browsers:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode
- https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode

Comment: https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/ explains why UK gov switched from type="number" to this solution.

Comment: Can still type any character if you have a physical keyboard

Comment: @vsync The OP and youjin never mentioned that it won't be possible. There lot of another posts handling this - for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Comment: Heads up for anyone not reading the other answers on this page. There is no validation performed with this method. The developer has to provide a regex pattern to validate against (and/or a JS function). That would need to include all possibilities for the given input, eg. digits-only, min/max values, decimals, negatives, scientific notation, and international formats, just to name the obvious ones which `type=number` currently handles "automatically."

Answer (score 46):

Try using `input type="tel"` instead. It pops up a keyboard with numbers, and it doesn’t show spin boxes. It requires no JavaScript or CSS or plugins or anything else.

Comment: This solution does not currently do any validation in any browsers like `type=number` does.

Comment: [The telephone keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aiLAa.png) is not as good as [the number keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gZRfo.png), though it’s far better than [the text keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2m6Yr.png). The telephone keyboard has irrelevant letters and symbols that are omitted from the number keyboard. (Tested with [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/T2VRE/show/) on Android 4.2.)

Comment: there is no "." in the tel keyboard :-<

Comment: This is not a solution, and by the HTML5 standards its stupid.
input[tel] is for phone numbers, input[number] is for generic numbers, including floating point ones. So this is not a solution at all.

Answer (score 20):

**Only add this css to remove spinner on input of number**

```
/* For Firefox */

input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}



/* Webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome */

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are trying to hide controls the browser adds, it should be a hint that you are misusing that input type.

### Standard Conformance Issues

From the [HTML spec on type=number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate):

> The `type=number` state is **not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number**. For example, it would be inappropriate for credit card numbers or US postal codes.

(Emphasis is mine)

### Usability Issues

The `<input type=number>` was found to be problematic during [a usability study](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/) performed by the GOV.UK team. This team maintains one of the world's best known design systems and concludes that this input type:

> - cannot be [dictated or selected when using Dragon Naturally
>   Speaking](https://github.com/alphagov/reported-bugs/issues/34)
> - appears as [unlabeled in NVDA's element list](https://github.com/alphagov/reported-bugs/issues/41)
> - appears as a [spin button in NVDA's object navigation, which has an edit field and two buttons inside](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/9675#issuecomment-499977041) - those buttons are unlabeled,
>   but decrease/increase the value
> - is reported as [unlabeled edit field](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/9675#issuecomment-499977041) when using nvda+tab

### Alternative Solution

Instead, they recommend to use `<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">` which comes down to the combined answers of @team_steve and @youjin. This not only hides the spin boxes, it also improves the overall usability of the element.

It comes without saying that additional validation needs to be done, along with a helpful error text.

```html
<label>Postal Code
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" size="5">
</label>
```

Comment: Can still type in non-numeric characters - which is undesired. The usability thing is not always important, as the limitation effect of allowing to input only numbers, which is a huge plus

Comment: You can put in non-numeric characters but not submit the form. I'd argue that's a plus because this way you can detect errors and give a proper validation message.

If someone mistypes but only can put in numbers, the values might be right according to the rules but not from a user point of view.

For example if someone types in `1K`, they mean `1000`. But if the `K` can't be typed in, you cannot detect this mistake. The input will be `1`, which is not what was meant.

Comment: I don’t understand your argument, @vsync. In such web-apps w/o `<form>` elements, validation needs to be implemented anyway. And an appropriate error message will be way more user friendly than messing with the user’s input. You got the evidence right in the links.

Comment: @Andy - I've deleted the comment. I think I commented on the wrong answer, because it doesn't fit, so I just removed it all together.

Comment: The input correctly forbids non-numeric characters because of the supplied pattern. What does @vsync mean that it does allow, maybe browser support is better for the `pattern` attribute now?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use number specific attributes like `min` and `max`.

Comment: How about decimals? Scientific format, negative values, international formatting? Now the dev has to write regexes for all those possibilities?

Answer (score 18):

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)

Answer (score 12):

I've encountered this problem with a `input[type="datetime-local"]`, which is similar to this problem.

And I've found a way to overcome this kind of problems.

First, you must turn on chrome's shadow-root feature by "DevTools -> Settings -> General -> Elements -> Show user agent shadow DOM"

Then you can see all **shadowed DOM elements**, for example, for `<input type="number">`, the full element with shadowed DOM is:

```html
<input type="number">
  <div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
    <div id="editing-view-port">
      <div id="inner-editor"></div>
    </div>
    <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button" id="spin"></div>
  </div>
</input>
```

[image: shadow DOM of input[type="number"]

And according to these info, you can draft some CSS to hide unwanted elements, just as @Josh said.

Answer (score 5):

To make this work in Safari I found adding `!important` to the *webkit* adjustment forces the spin button to be hidden.

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

I am still having trouble working out a solution for Opera as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is more better answer i would like to suggest on mouse over and without mouse over

```
input[type='number'] {
  appearance: textfield;
}
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type='number']:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type='number']:hover::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none; 
 margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Not what you asked for, but I do this because of a focus bug in WebKit with spinboxes:

```
// temporary fix for focus bug with webkit input type=number ui
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("AppleWebKit") > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mobile") == -1)
{
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]");
    for (var el in els)
        el.type = "text";
}
```

It might give you an idea to help with what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe change the number input with javascript to text input when you don't want a spinner;

```
document.getElementById('myinput').type = 'text';
```

and stop the user entering text;

```
  document.getElementById('myinput').onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
    || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
    || e.keyCode == 8
    || e.keyCode == 9)) {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

then have the javascript change it back in case you do want a spinner;

```
document.getElementById('myinput').type = 'number';
```

it worked well for my purposes

Answer (score 3):

On Firefox for Ubuntu, just using

```
    input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

did the trick for me.

Adding

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Would lead me to

> Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-outer-spin-button’. 
>   Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

everytime I tried. Same for the inner spin button.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this to work

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button
  -webkit-appearance: none
  appearance: none
  margin: 0

/* Firefox */
input[type=number]
  -moz-appearance: textfield
```

The extra line of `appearance: none` was key to me.

Answer (score 3):

In WebKit and Blink-based browsers & All Kind Of Browser  use the following CSS :

```
/* Disable Number Arrow */
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: others wrote the **same** thing years before, so why did you choose to add this still?

Answer (score 2):

For me on chrome nothing has worked but `display: none`.

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Credits to @philfreo for pointing it out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
```

```html
<input id="test" type="number">
```

Answer (score -2):

This like your css code:

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers.