# Chrome input type="number" CSS styling

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I have the following input type="number":

```
<input id="myid" type="number" name="input" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

In Chrome only you can see 2 arrows that increase or decrease the value. Is there a way to style those controls. Something like:

```
#myid::-webkit-
```

Comment: This is not chrome specific, use css to style your input fields like you would do with a normal web page

Comment: @ArtWorkAD is it chrome specific as the increase, decrease buttons are created by Chrome's input type="number" HTML5 support

Comment: Did you succeeded ? I don't manage to increase their size...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<s>I just ran into this myself.</s> Actually, I was trying to get rid of them, **however**, the same rules in the the linked SO question still should apply for altering appearance as well. I found the solution in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box). Look at the accepted answer, it works like a charm.

Comment: Also see this [question with actual styling examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266888/styling-html5-number-input-spin-box-in-chrome), too

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to find the number input's default arrow styles.
Hope this helps.
Heres a list of all the styles found in the number input element (found using chromes inspect mode):

```
1.  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
2.  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
3.  -webkit-user-select: text;
4.  background-color: white;
5.  border-bottom-style: inset;
6.  border-bottom-width: 2px;
7.  border-left-style: inset;
8.  border-left-width: 2px;
9.  border-right-style: inset;
10. border-right-width: 2px;
11. border-top-style: inset;
12. border-top-width: 2px;
13. color: black;
14. cursor: auto;
15. display: inline-block;
16. font-family: Arial;
17. font-size: 13px;
18. font-style: normal;
19. font-variant: normal;
20. font-weight: normal;
21. height: 16px;
22. letter-spacing: normal;
23. line-height: normal;
24. margin-bottom: 2px;
25. margin-left: 2px;
26. margin-right: 2px;
27. margin-top: 2px;
28. padding-bottom: 1px;
29. padding-left: 0px;
30. padding-right: 0px;
31. padding-top: 1px;
32. text-align: -webkit-auto;
33. text-indent: 0px;
34. text-shadow: none;
35. text-transform: none;
36. width: 151px;
37. word-spacing: 0px;
Styles
________________________________________

element.style {
}
Matched CSS Rules
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type]), input[type="color"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="week"] {
1.  padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex {
1.  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
2.  padding: 1px;
3.  background-color: white;
4.  border: 2px inset;
5.  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
6.  -webkit-user-select: text;
7.  cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex, datagrid {
1.  margin: 0em;
2.  font: -webkit-small-control;
3.  color: initial;
4.  letter-spacing: normal;
5.  word-spacing: normal;
6.  line-height: normal;
7.  text-transform: none;
8.  text-indent: 0px;
9.  text-shadow: none;
10. display: inline-block;
11. text-align: -webkit-auto;
}
Pseudo ::-webkit-input-placeholder element
user agent stylesheet
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, isindex::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
1.  color: darkGray;
}
Pseudo ::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container element
user agent stylesheet
input::-webkit-input-speech-button {
1.  -webkit-appearance: -webkit-input-speech-button;
2.  display: inline-block;
}
Pseudo ::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display element
user agent stylesheet
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
1.  -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button;
2.  display: inline-block;
3.  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
Pseudo ::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display element
user agent stylesheet
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
1.  margin: 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
1.  -webkit-appearance: outer-spin-button;
2.  display: inline-block;
3.  margin-left: 2px;
4.  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```