# How do you get rid of the input type="date" arrow box beside of the input?

Tags: html, forms

I've tried various things and have not found anything that works. I thought it would just be something like:

```
input[type="date"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

But this didn't work. Does any know how to remove them?

Answer (score 5):

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for mobile browsers :( Any idea about that?

Comment: Perhaps this is a more modern answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587645/239211

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box/4298216#4298216) which deals with the spinners on `input[type="number"]` elements (found via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671992/chrome-input-type-number-css-styling)).

Comment: Says a lot about SO's usefulness when the first search result is straight back here :)