# Remove all styling and functionality from <input type="date" /> besides keyboard

Tags: html, forms, css, datetime, webkit

I've been having a lot of issues figuring out how to get rid of all browser functionality associated with `<input type="date" />` but keeping it as that type in order to trigger appropriate software keyboards on mobile.

So far:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-inner-spin-button { display: none !important; }
  ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none !important; }
```

These seem to be all values associated to this input type, but adding display none of them basically renders input unusable, i.e. no text or placeholders are visible.

Comment: Be aware that at this time (April 2017), `<input type="date" />` is not currently supported in either Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get rid of all browser functionality associated with `<input type="date" />`

## readonly attribute

Any form element can take a `readonly` attribute.

**Example:**

```
<input type="date" readonly />
```

---

## disabled attribute

Any form element can take a `disabled` attribute.

**Example:**

```
<input type="date" disabled />
```

---

## pointer-events: none;

For what it's worth you can also style your `<input />` with the following CSS:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

**Example:**

```css
input['type="date"'] {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: I guess you misread, it says: _to get rid of all..._***but*** _keyboard_

Comment: Ah. I think, maybe, I just don't understand the question.