# Split arrow when HTML input type is number

Tags: html, css, input

Can anyone tell me how to split arrows when using HTML input type is number

```
<input type="number">

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

By using above css i can able to hide arrows. Like that is there is anyway to split arrows.

Comment: You can implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21775054/5247200) solution and create your own image.

Comment: @David Thanks, But this is not what i expect,