# Javascript Validation for Positive Integer Only Input

Tags: javascript, validation, html-input

I have two text boxes, in it will only be allowed positive integers.
If any alphabetical values or any other characters (e.g. %$&*£") are entered, an error message should be displayed and the values must not render a table.

```
 <input type="button" value="total" name="B3" onclick="powerOf();">
```

This line allows for calculation to be made, how can this validation stop this from happening
when the incorrect values are entered?? As of now minus numbers are calculated and entering alphabets produces an empty table which is not quite what I was going for:

```
(no1== no1.match(/^-\d+$/) ? alert("First number must be positive"): no1 = no1 ? no1 : 0);
        (no2== no2.match(/^-\d+$/) ? alert("Second number must be positive"): no2 = no2 ? no2 : 0)

        var range1 = parseInt(no1);
        var range2 = parseInt(no2);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the validation code?

Comment: Do you want to roll out your own or use an existing validation library?

Comment: This question has been already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

Comment: @Pointy what I had was pretty useless as I am a beginner, however posted it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you can do this simply via HTML5 form validation:

```
<input type="number" min="1">
```

Then you won't be able to submit the form unless the entered value is a number higher than 1. This only seems to work in Chrome though.

---

To answer your question, what you're looking for is `event.preventDefault()`. If you change your onclick function to:

```
 <input type="button" value="total" name="B3" onclick="powerOf(event);">
```

then you can run `event.preventDefault()` in the `powerOf` function, and when you run that, the event will be "cancelled". For example:

```
function powerOf(event) {
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(document.getElementById('input-1').value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

that will cancel the click event when the value of the input with `id="input-1"` is *not* digits only.

See [this demo](http://jsbin.com/rinot/1) for a working example.

Comment: Firefox 26.0 is perfectly happy to submit a form with a "number" `<input>` field whose value isn't a number.

Comment: @Pointy that's weird, I just checked http://caniuse.com/form-validation and it says FF should support it. After [testing it myself](http://jsbin.com/hireb/1/edit/) though, it does indeed seem to work just fine, not even recognising the input as CSS-`:invalid`. I've updated my answer (it doesn't seem to work in IE11 either).

Comment: Yes, it does work in Chrome. Personally I find the "number" input implementation in Chrome to be really ugly, so I only use "number" on touch-screen devices because there it also influences the on-screen keyboard layout.

Comment: @Pointy [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298216/1256925) apparently seems to do the trick: [demo](http://jsbin.com/hireb/2/). (got that link via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797289/1256925)) The advantage over just using the `type="text"` now is that you can in- and decrement via the up and down arrow keys, and the form validation in Chrome.

Comment: @Joeytje50 the validation seems to be working, but the preventDefault isn't having followed your instructions.

Comment: @rookJCR I've added a working demo to my answer. Does that help? The form only submits when your input contains numbers only.