# trigger number pad on focus in html input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web application for tablets. In the application there is an input element that requires an integer input. When the user clicks on the input element usually the letter keyboard pops up and then the user has to switch to the number pad. Is there an attribute that one can specify so that the tablet pops up a number pad instead?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try number type:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

One of these types:

```
<input type="tel" ...>

<input type="number" ...>
```

The actual behaviour will depend on the tablet's platform. On iOS, the `number` keyboard has integers and arithmetic operators, and the `tel` keyboard has large digits and a #/* key only.

[Source](http://zooskdev.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/mobile-web-design-use-html5-to-trigger-the-appropriate-keyboard-for-form-inputs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<input type="number" />`.

And if you want to remove arrows you can check : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box)