# Disable webkit's input mask with input type=“time”?

Tags: javascript, css, .net, html

I want to remove all the webkit stuff (chrome) associated with the type time.  I don't want to change the type.

```
<input type="time">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dDqX4/

I have found similar questions removing the webkit stuff.

[Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box)

Thanks!

Update:
Chrome
[image]

IE
[image]

As you can see chrome breaks its.

Comment: why you can't use type=text?

Comment: You don't want to change type in the markup - are you open to change it programmaticaly?

Comment: As long as it fills my control with time and it works right in chrome and IE :).  The only I have gotten it to is with type time. In other words I need a date picker and a time picker. I don't want to use the Trent control either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-millisecond-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-week-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Where were you two years ago?! :)

Comment: Lol, didn't have an account back then. Came here looking for an answer. Found your post and later found this solution. So posted it for future reference. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button,
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dDqX4/3/

Comment: The input mask is still there in chrome...  The buttons are gone but thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=time] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want your input to remain visible when valid but not in focus

```
input:not( :focus ) {
  color: transparent;
}
input:valid {
  color: inherit;
}
```