# ng input number with input type = text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use angular's number validation, however it looks like it requires input type=number? usually this would be fine, except I don't want the up and down arrows that appear to the right of this type of input by default.

Is there an alternative solution? I tried using ng input number with input text but it didn't work for me :/

Comment: for type = number, it is the browser that draws those arrows for you, not angular. And sure, you can use input with type = text, but you just have to write the javascript code that will limit the model so that all non numeric input values are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="number" />`

And read this article: [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box)