# HTML5 <input type="number"> CSS customization

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML5 number input type

```
<input type="number">
```

My requirement is that the user should be able to set the value only through UP & DOWN arrow (spinners). User shouldn't be able to enter the value manually. Is it possible using **CSS only**?

I am using *node-webkit*.

Similar to this approach:

- [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box)

Comment: What does adding `readonly` attribute to the `input` do?

Comment: i need the spinners to stay. adding readonly to input removes the spinners too!

Comment: Not possible with CSS only. *Possible* with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is not possible to use CSS only. Here is a small script to do that in case you want:

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 40) {event.preventDefault()}"/>
```

Comment: I'd exclude the `Enter` or `Backspace` keys as well.

Comment: @trungDQ will it on android too?

Comment: @ShouryaSharma you should consider to exclude `Enter` (keyCode = 13) and `Backspace` (keyCode = 8) keys as @Hashem suggested, just will give user ability to submit the form using `Enter` key, and the `Backspace` to..., you got the idea. Just add them into the condition.

Comment: @ShouryaSharma, I am not sure if this works on android. In case it doesn't work, just do some test to find the keyCode of the `Up` and `Down` key, then put them in the condition statement.

Comment: it doesn't matter if the keys don't work as I require the spinners to work in node-webkits' kiosk mode (without keyboard).

Comment: The spinner won't be affected at all.

Answer (score 0):

use Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

})
```