# how to remove number incrementor in textboxes for number fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

For number based fields in django a incrementor widget is placed to the righ in each textbox.  How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is an html5 thing and is called a spinner.  It can be solved with this css:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

Referenced from: [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)