# Issue with opening numeric keypad in devices

Tags: javascript, html

For opening only numeric keypad in devices we will use fallowing two approaches,

1. input field of type number
2. input field of type tel

But in above two approaches we have issues are there. They are

1. If we use input field of type 'number', it is showing up arrow and down arrow for that field in chrome browsers.
2. If we use input field of type 'tel', the arrow buttons is not working.

How can I solve this one?

Comment: option one sounds like the better one to focus on. see if this question helps you remove the arrows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Answer (score 1):

type number is not fully supported by all browsers. 
See http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number 
to get further information on browser support.