# Hide HTML5 input type number arrow with a css class?

Tags: css, html, input

I've seen this question asked before in here [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790935/3809894), and some others have asked with a specific request for a Browser, in my case what i want to know is: Is there a way to create a css class like `.no-spin` to hide the spin arrows across browsers?

I tried:

```
.no-spin {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

But no luck, I don't really know that much about css in fact...

Comment: No CSS required.

now a days you can use <input inputmode="numeric" ..

reference : https://youtu.be/alGcULGtiv8?t=630

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Answer

```css
.no-spin::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .no-spin::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.no-spin {
    -moz-appearance:textfield !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="no-spin"/>
```

**Note:** Placing the `*-moz-appearance*` declaration inside the `*.no-spin::-webkit*` selector will not work in Firefox, as of 2020. To get this to work in all browsers, the `-moz-appearance` declaration must be placed in a new class selector, that is just `.no-spin` by itself.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp

Comment: Is this solution supported in most browsers and devices?

Comment: it should work based on the !important for safari and the rest for chrome and firefox happy for community to suggest any improvements I might have missed..

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome, **however**, beware that the up and down arrow keys will still cause the number to be incremented or decremented.

Comment: -moz-appearance:textfield !important;
needs to apply to the input itself, not the spin-buttons. Changing that will make it work in FF.

Answer (score 4):

You can try just in your html

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]">
```

or if you really want to keep it as number, although as security doesn't change anything maybe try in your css this:

```
.no-spin, .no-spin:hover, no-spin:focus {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hide arrows of input number

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
    }
    input[type="number"] {
      -moz-appearance: textfield; /* Firefox */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in all browsers:

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none; 
}
```