# Multiple patterns in <input>

Tags: html, forms, input

I am trying to use multiple patterns for an input-field in HTML5.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*.{5,10}" name="plz">
```

My current input field does not work. Only the second pattern `.{5,10}` is relevant for the submit. The first attribute `\d*` hast no effects.

Comment: What's the expected input ?

Comment: A postal code (zip code). In germany all codes have five numbers. And on mobile devies the num-keyboard should appear: ´\d*´

Comment: `pattern="[0-9]{5}"` or `pattern="\d{5}"`

Comment: works fine, thank you! On mobile devices the normal text-keyboard is shown, but the number-keyboard should appears.

Comment: add `input type='number'`

Comment: And for your upcoming question its showing spinner..here you can find answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Comment: Now a normal text-keyboard with numbers on top is appearing but there is an option for an numbers-only keyboard causes by "\d*"

Comment: you can try this..it should fullfill your purpose `\d{5}`

Comment: Sorry, no result. Now the `{5}` isn't noted as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" pattern="([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{1})">
```

and just accept `AESE640526HOCCNL05`...

Hope this can help you.