# Regular Expression max-length is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function test() {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,11}$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is correct to take only integer but max-length is not working. It takes more than 11 digits.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You're passing it a single character, which satisfies `{1,11}`.

Comment: This is a frequent question, the reson is that you test a single char against the regex. You need to use `maxlength` attribute. You may also add an `pattern="\d{1,11}"` attribute to check the input validity on submit.

Comment: I want to give permission only to write digits and max length should be eleven(11) digits.

Comment: so how to make it  to take maximum 11 digits

Comment: If you want to control input into an input element, use the `pattern` attribute, which has multiple advantages, including the ability to style the input with CSS rules such as `input:invalid`.

Comment: You need to test the entire value, rather than just the single char from the key event.

Comment: no I want to check single digit because it will not let the user to write against the rule in the text box. If I want to check a string then user can write all string first then this string will be tested...?

Comment: Well, you can't detect the overall length from a single digit. What event are you calling this test routine on?

Comment: Actually I am using onkeypress

Answer (score 1):

This kind of manual input validation is not how applications are usually written these days in HTML5. It is a throwback to the bad old jQuery days. It is a bad user experience to simply throw away keystrokes--the user has no idea what he is doing wrong, and may think his keyboard is broken. If you trap on the `keyup` event, you will also miss some scenarios, such as when the user has dragged and dropped text into the input box. Or if the user types <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste text into the box, you will end up looking at that keystroke instead of the characters pasted in.

HTML5 adds the `pattern` attribute to the `input` element which allows you to do regexp-based validation. This has a number of advantages. For instance, invalid entries can be styled using CSS with the `:invalid` pseudo-class. Invalid form entries will automatically prevent submits, and put up user-friendly balloons describing the specific problem.

In your case:

```
<input pattern="\\d{1, 11}">
```

Note that no `^` or `$` anchors are required--they are implicit in this case.

No JS is required.

Answer (score 0):

as you said:

> I want to give permission only to write digits and max length should be eleven(11) digits.

you can:

1. use an `<input type="number" maxlength="11" />`
2. use a regex `/^\d{1,11}$/`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
function valueIsValid(v) {

  return /^\d{1,11}$/.test(v);
}
  var foo = document.querySelector('#foo');

foo
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log('valid', valueIsValid(foo.value), foo.value)
  })
;
});
```

```html
<input id="foo" />
```

Comment: in your first point. the textbox showing ascending descending arrows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Comment: I am using <input type="number"> but still these characters e.+- is written into the type='number'

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question. Try something like this.

```
var count = 0;

function test() {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,11}$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

   if(count<11){
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        count=0;
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
     count++;
   }
   return false;   
}
```