# Change Html control in EditorforModel MVC

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, scaffold, editorformodel

I am using EditorforModel for Login Page,
this my model

```
[Required]
    public int UserId
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [HiddenInput]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string ReturnUrl
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

This is my view:

```
    @model MVCIdentityLogin.Models.LogInModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>


@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <p>
        <button type="submit"> Log In</button>
    </p>
}
```

my view as :
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFJY4.png)
this view Userid input field has increase and decrease button. How to remove it? 
I check this html that is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)

Comment: I already viewed this , but i want solution in MVC environment, NO CSS

Answer (score 0):

just add this [DataType(DataType.Text)]
 attribute in Userid property
    like this

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public int UserId
{
    get; set;
}
```