# Is there a way to remove the increase/decrease arrows in input type="number" for textboxfor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Is there any way to remove these in input (type="number")?

```html
<input type="number" />
```

It's for the users to input their phone numbers.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7Wn.png)

Comment: Since you title includes `TextBoxFor()` I can only assume you have not tagged this correctly (should be [tag:asp.net-mvc]). But `TextBoxFor()` will never add `type="number"`. Only `EditorFor()` can add that, and only if the property is a numeric type - and a phone number property should never be a numeric type - it needs to be a `string` (using css for this is just crazy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)

Comment: now a days you can use <input inputmode="numeric" ..

reference : https://youtu.be/alGcULGtiv8?t=630

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can be done through CSS if you wish,

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this does not work in firefox 97.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Just these was enought for my code.

```
.input[type=number] {  
   &::-webkit-inner-spin-button{ display: none; }
   -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some description / reasoning why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.