# Can i hide the HTML5 time input spin box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way across browsers to hide/remove the spin boxes I am looking for a CSS or JavaScript method to prevent the up/down arrows from appearing.

```html
<input type="time" name="time1">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate was targeting `input[type="number"]`, but that the same vendor-specific pseudo classes work for `input[type="time"]` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```css
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```