# HTML input box : numeric values only

Tags: html

I have this HTML form with an input field.
I want only numeric values to be inputted.

Problem is, when I hover the mouse over the input field, a scroll bar appears on the right. How to avoid this?

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <br/>
    <label class="control-label">Hours spent :</label>
    <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" placeholder="Please input total number of hours spent on this job." class="form-control">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have to problems? or you only need the input to accept only numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them with CSS, assuming you mean the input spinners.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
   -webkit-appearance: textfield; 
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on [thatstevensguy.com](https://www.thatstevensguy.com/programming/disable-arrows-on-number-inputs/)

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
 
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <br/>
    <label class="control-label">Hours spent :</label>
    <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" placeholder="Please input total number of hours spent on this job." class="form-control">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See below

```css
/* For Firefox */

input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}


/* Webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome */

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <br/>
    <label class="control-label">Hours spent :</label>
    <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" placeholder="Please input total number of hours spent on this job." class="form-control">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation.