# Angular 7 with material - prevent input number scrolling

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material

Could you help me, how can I prevent scrolling the number an input number field in Angular? I use it with material.

Thanks,
Gábor

Comment: What do you mean by *input number scrolling*? Please [include your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I mean when the mouse is in the input field which type is number, I can scroll with my mouse wheel, and it decreases or increases the value. It is not a good thing, because when the user "forget" the mouse in the field, it changes the value instead of scroll the page

Comment: Please review this article on how to write a good SO question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, I believe what you're after is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have found the css way, but it only removes the arrows, and the scrolling is also working now.