# HTML input type for phone number

Tags: html, css

I want to know which type can I use for input phone number.

I can type letters when I do:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required>
```

Also, I want to delete that arrow in right:

```
<input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" required>
```

[image]

What I want is an input to type only phone number.

Comment: Why is laravel connected to this?

Comment: Why is css connected to this?

Comment: it's just html issue and easy available

Comment: Also phone number can be entered in many formats. To use that formats you could add on keydown listener with javascript and remove everything except certain chars. You can do it with regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)

Comment: Please keep in mind that a phone number may not only consist of numeric digits, but also of special characters like `+` or `()` and may even contain letters. The latter is called a [Phoneword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword). So the unrestricted `type="tel"` without any pattern is the most versatile input type for international phone numbers.

Comment: @feeela a phone with letters is not a valid phone format, also parentheses and hyphens are not mandatory. So imho the only requirement would be to account for the plus sign to distinguish international prefixes, other than that a phone could be all digits

Comment: @Xriuk Nope, the requirements should match whatever a user might input there. Which is different based on local practice. A user should be able to paste a valid phone number like `(011) [15]4-123-4567` into such a field. For a list of possible phone number formats please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers

Answer (score 18):

Using `tel` you can just add some validation to allow only numbers (you can also add a `+` beforehand and include whatever country code you need).

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{11,14}" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will bring up an error when you submit

Or you can restrict to numbers and hide the arrow by doing this:

```css
.no-arrow {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.no-arrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
.no-arrow::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.no-arrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" class="no-arrow" value="" type="number">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

All of the above solutions do not avoid the user adding non-number in your input, for example, when you set pattern attribute on `<input />` tag, the user can enter non-number `char`, but when the user submit the form then browser error appear

if you want limit your input just in number , you have to do this with `js`

> Pure Js

```js
const inputValidation = (e) => {
 
    // get value form event
     const value = e.target.value

    // validate value
    const validatedValue = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    return validatedValue;


}
```

> React JS

```js
// Implement your input state
const [mobile, setMobile] = React.useState("");


// validate value
const numberHandler = val => {
        const validatedValue = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        setMobile(validatedValue);
 };
```

your input tag

```
 return (
    <div>
     <input type="tel" value={mobile} onChange={e => numberHandler(e)} />
    </div>

  )
```

Also, you can show an alert to the user if they enter invalid data

```js
const numberHandler = val => {
        const validatedValue = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
          
      + // implement alert
      +  if (validatedValue === "" && val !== "") {
      +    alert('you must enter number only')
      +    return
      +  }
        setMobile(validatedValue);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If just by removing the arrows solves your problem then you can try including css to disable it:

```
#phone::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
#phone::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

I would suggest using this js library for formatting input fields:

[tel input js](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none;  work for webkit browser only (+ edge), you should include in your answer the -mo- prefixed property and the (still unsupported) unprefixed one.