# Vertical line appearing in input type=number on Mac version of Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, input, safari

I've come across a bug in the Mac version of Safari where on a number input field I have a vertical line appearing in the box. I've checked it on an iphone as well as Windows based browsers and it isn't present on anything else.
**Edit: Turnip has pointed out that it happens in Chrome on Windows as well. I've checked it this morning and it happens when you click inside the input box.**

The code I'm using to generate the html is:

```html
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text no-spinners" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

The link to an example of the page in question is [link](https://shop.alchemillarestaurant.uk/product/100-gift-voucher/)

[image]

**Edit: updated the code block to reflect what's rendered client side rather than the server side code.**

Comment: You should remove your server-side code from examples that are client-side questions.

Comment: FYI, I see the line when using Chrome.

Comment: @Turnip Thanks. I'd not noticed it in Chrome although it seems to be when the input field is in it's focus state.

Comment: Are you talking about the blinking cursor line?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb It's the vertical black line next to the number in the input box. It's not blinking for me on screen however.

Answer (score 0):

It's the spinner on the input. You've styled it using the `no-spinners` class, by adding border and height to it. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298216/2950032) to correctly hide it, if that was your intention in the first place.