# I am trying to create a text box which allows only numbers using typescripts. See below example

Tags: typescript, aurelia

using typescript I want to create a textbox whixh allows on numbers.

## textbox-alpha.ts

```
    import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class textboxNumber {

@bindable public allownumber : number;
} 
  function onlynumber(allownumber) {
    allownumber = (allownumber) ? allownumber : event;
    var charCode = (allownumber.charCode) ? allownumber.charCode : ((allownumber.keyCode) ? allownumber.keyCode :
  ((allownumber.which) ? allownumber.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
    (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {

        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

## textbox-alpha.html

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="onlynumber(allownumber)" required />
```

Comment: Note that this approach will not handle copy/paste into the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pattern` attribute to validate the input on form submission and let the browser do the work.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  // preventing the form from being submitted so that multiple inputs can be tested
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('submit');
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="-?\d*" title="Value must be an integer" required />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a custom element for this as there is a built in input type for this.

`<input type="number" />`

Comment: Right! but I don't want to do that way.

Comment: Why not? Please elaborate. Is there a specific requirement that won't be met with this?

Comment: when we use type=number than you see some up and down icon in right and side corner of the textbox. and thats a things i dont like.

Comment: I mean, it is possible to hide those icons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box