# How to Remove Arrow on Input type Number with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, input, numbers, tailwind-css

I have an input of type number, and I want to remove the increment/decrement arrows that come with it by default. How can I do that with Tailwind CSS? I looked up for it but found nothing that solves this problem.

```
 input type="number" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" className="border p-4 outline-none"
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

So i found the solution for this -> On your global.css you have to add

```
@layer base {
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for specifie the code Zack

Comment: This didnot work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me either :/

Comment: It's working thanks!

Comment: Would this work with Firefox?

Comment: This didn't work for me. See RicardoVallejo's answer which is very similar.

Comment: @Surya If you want it to work in firefox as well you have to add `appearance: textfield` to `input[type="number"]`

Comment: @MaximeDoré Thanks for clarifying. Should be included in the answer as answers should be cross browser as much as possible.

Answer (score 66):

Discovered a pure class way to do this that works both with Firefox and Chrome

```html
<input
  type="number"
  class="[appearance:textfield] [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none" 
  />
```

Thanks to these references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745933/1570165
- [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)
- https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6972

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 40):

Adding to @Tyron answer which is correct.

```
     @layer base {
        input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
        input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        input[type='number'] {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          margin: 0;
          -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
        }
     }
```

Add compatibility to Mozilla

ref [w3schools/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)

Comment: @Tyron did not work for me, this one did. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms")({
      strategy: 'class', // only generate classes
    }),
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.arrow-hide':{
          '&::-webkit-inner-spin-button':{
            '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
            'margin': 0
          },
          '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button':{
            '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
            'margin': 0
          },
        }
      }
      )
    })
  ],
}
```

add this to your tailwind `config.js` and use as a normal tailwind class.

Comment: You can also add '-moz-appearance': 'textfield !important' for this to work in firefox, just before '.arrow-hide' closing

Answer (score 4):

```
[-moz-appearance:_textfield] [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I add this into my global.css to hide an arrow from specific className:

```css
.hide-arrow[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.hide-arrow[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **select** component, inputs don't have arrows.

```html
<select type="number" id="amount" name="amount">
    <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
```

**Solution for all selects**

```js
@layer base {
    select {
        appearance: none !important;
    }
}
```

**Solution for specific types**

```js
@layer base {
    select[type='number'] {
        appearance: none !important;
    }
}
```

**With CDN**

```js
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer base {
        select[type='number'] {
            appearance: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" className="border p-4
outline-none appearance-none" />
```

this with tailwind here a link you can look on it
[tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance#removing-default-element-appearancea)

and with normal css :

```
<style>
  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<input
  type="number"
  placeholder="Numéro de téléphone"
  className="border p-4
  outline-none"
/>
```

Answer (score -3):

To remove the arrows you need to set `appearance` to `none` (source[https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp])

If you use TailwindCSS 3 you could try this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance, if you use TailwindCSS 2, this: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: `appearance-none` didn't work for me for `type="number"` but `[appearance:textfield]` worked instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745933/1570165
(worked with Firefox but not with Chrome)

Answer (score -3):

For Tailwind, you can search "appearance-none"

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance

This removed the default addon behaviors of different input types.

Comment: not working any more