# Tailwind appearance-none class not working for input field of type number

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to remove the arrow/spinners that come natively with a [number typed input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4TDF.png). I understand that this can easily be done following the article [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp), by setting the `-webkit-appearance` and  `-moz-appearance`. With that said, here is my current implementation using a CSS class called `.no-spin`.

```css
.no-spin::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.no-spin::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.no-spin {
    -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Number Input Field w/o spinner</label>
  <input class="no-spin" type="number">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Number Input Field w/ spinner</label>
  <input type="number">
</div>
```

However, since I am using Tailwind, I am looking for a possible solution where I do not have to resort to CSS classes, just like the other components of my project. I have already tried using an `appearance-none` class as suggested by the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance) but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could add `[appearance:textfield]` which would be generated as:

```
.\[appearance\:textfield\] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
          appearance: textfield;
}
```

That should do the trick

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="m-2 bg-green-200">
  <input class="[appearance:textfield] m-4 bg-gray-100" type="number" name="" placeholder="1" id="" />
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Also, running the code snippet still produces the native input with the arrow/spinners.  I have edited my original post to include the intended CSS that I am attempting to produce with Tailwind.

Comment: @AmehPls this probably works for Firefox but not for Chrome