# Hide Up & Down Arrow Buttons (Spinner) in Input Number - Firefox 29

Tags: css, firefox, input, spinner

On Firefox 28, I'm using `<input type="number">` works great because it brings up the numerical keyboard on input fields which should only contain numbers.

In Firefox 29, using number inputs displays spin buttons at the right side of the field, which looks like crap in my design. I really don't need the buttons, because they are useless when you need to write something like a 6~10 digit number anyway.

Is it possible to disable this with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: can you use `input type text`?

Comment: If you don't want the spin arrows, then don't use `type="number"`.  You can use `type="text"` and the `pattern` attribute to set a regex to make sure it's a number.

Comment: maybe this help you: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/

Comment: I don't can change the type, because i have some scripts where I use jquery selector input[type=number].

Comment: -webkit-inner-spin-button -webkit-outer-spin-button with -webkit-appearance: none; margin: 0; 
Dont Work in Firefox.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: `type="number"` is required for mobile browsers to show the numeric keyboard instead of the full keyboard.

Comment: `<input type="tel">` it's only numbers and it doesn't include spinners.

Comment: Changing `type="text"` is a bad idea because touch devices will show the wrong keyboard.

Comment: setting `type="text"` is a bad idea, you will have to make sure you enter only numeric characters and also you will have to use separate validation if you want to make use of the `min` or `max` attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box)

Answer (score 621, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://jwatt.org/2013/12/11/input-type-number-coming-to-mozilla), you need to set `-moz-appearance:textfield;` on the `input`.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01"/>
```

Comment: I wrapped this in `@-moz-document url-prefix() { ... }` and it does what I want: hides the spinners in Firefox, where they look bad, but keep them alive in other browsers, including ones that bring up the numeric keyboard as the OP mentioned.

Comment: Some more useful information from Geoff Graham: [Numeric Inputs – A Comparison of Browser Defaults](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/)

Comment: how we can remove from IE ?

Comment: @Bhupinderkumar: As far as I can see, neither IE11 nor Edge display spinner buttons on numeric inputs.

Comment: this works and indeed it removes the spinners, but then you are now able to enter alphanumeric characters into it. Hope somebody finds a way to handle that scenario without having to check the entered keys if they are numbers or not.

Comment: @JovanniG: Even if you don't remove the spinners, you can still enter non-numeric characters into the input in Firefox. Try it with the [demo on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). Chrome prevents non-numeric input in both examples.

Comment: @alxndr: The question was about Firefox, not Chrome. The Chrome part was added later by Jan-Terje Sørensen. But thanks for the down-vote anyway.

Comment: @alxndr: Also, I've just tried the "Run code snippet" in Chrome 66, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 60):

It's worth pointing out that the default value of `-moz-appearance` on these elements is `number-input` in Firefox.

If you want to hide the spinner by default, you can set `-moz-appearance: textfield` initially, and if you *want* the spinner to appear on `:hover`/`:focus`, you can overwrite the previous styling with `-moz-appearance: number-input`.

```css
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="number"]:hover,
input[type="number"]:focus {
    -moz-appearance: number-input;
}
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

I thought someone might find that helpful since I recently had to do this in attempts to improve consistency between Chrome/FF (since this is the way number inputs behave by default in Chrome).

If you want to see all the available values for `-moz-appearance`, you can find them [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) (mdn).

Comment: `moz-appearance: number-input;` didn't work for me, but I just used "auto" instead.

Answer (score 13):

In `SASS`/`SCSS` style, you can write like this:

```
input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;/*For FireFox*/

  &::-webkit-inner-spin-button { /*For Webkits like Chrome and Safari*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Definitely this code style can use in `PostCSS`.

Answer (score 7):

```
/* for chrome */
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;}             


/* for mozilla */  
   input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue post Firefox update to 29.0.1, this is also listed out here
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=947728

Solutions:
They(Mozilla guys) have fixed this by introducing support for "-moz-appearance" for `<input type="number">`.
You just need to have a style associated with your input field with "`-moz-appearance:textfield;`".

I prefer the CSS way
E.g.:-

```
.input-mini{
-moz-appearance:textfield;}
```

Or

You can do it inline as well:

```
<input type="number" style="-moz-appearance: textfield">
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2021, there is a much better solution to make your firefox like Google Chrome.
You should use focus and hover, too.

```
input[type="number"] {
    appearance: none; /* textfield also works! */
}

input[type="number"]:focus, 
input[type="number"]:hover {
    appearance: auto;
}
```

for more information, please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Comment: This solution finally worked for me. Specifically the `appearance: auto;`. I also wanted to mention that `appearance: none;` no longer works, but `textfield` does.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
    input[type='number'] {
    appearance: none;
}
```

Solved in Firefox, Safari, Chrome. Also, `-moz-appearance: textfield;` is not supported anymore (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Answer (score 1):

I mixed few answers from answers above and from [How to remove the arrows from input[type="number"] in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107118/how-to-remove-the-arrows-from-inputtype-number-in-opera/22306944)
in scss:

```
input[type=number] {
  &,
  &::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  &::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: none;

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      -moz-appearance: number-input;
    }
  }
}

Tested on chrome, firefox, safari
```

Comment: Maybe you can move the browser prefix attributes like `-moz-`  to last to prevent override by none prefix attributes.


```
{
    appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```