# How do you stop input button fields doubling up on Firefox, Windows 7?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Does anyone know how to resolve this browser issue where button input fields double up on Windows 7 Firefox (v 31)?

The secondary buttons hide the number field.

You can view the +/- buttons in question that are next to the "Add to basket" button here...

http://instituteofleadership.org.uk/wp/product/personal-leadership-programme/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance:textfield;
}

/* hides the spin-button for chrome*/
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374725/4016757