# Hide psuedo element scoped to selector in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have been attempting without success to hide the spinner in number input fields for a single field using LESS.

I have been referring to the following SO Post:
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372903/hide-spinner-in-input-number-firefox-29)

I have tried the following with both the input-wrapper class and the class I have assigned to the input itself without any success.

```
.input-wrapper {

  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
       margin: 0;
  }

  input[type=number] {
      -moz-appearance:textfield;
  } 
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: What structure are you trying to match? Where is that classname?

Comment: @SLaks Well that is actually functioning I just had a separate error in my markup that was hard to spot, thank you though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Spinner in Input Number - Firefox 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372903/hide-spinner-in-input-number-firefox-29)