# How to stop the characters in Input type="text" field in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

My client requirement is as follows
1. The input field should be a text
2. It should not allow characters
3. It should have range of 0-100
4. Input format is 99.99

we are using angular 7. Pattern is not working for the validation

Can someone please help me. I am struggling from one day :(
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `type="number"`?

Comment: when I use a number, we get a up and down arrow which is not as part of requirement. Thanks

Comment: You can try the technique given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374725/1009922) to hide the arrows.

Comment: you can try using mask: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Comment: you can  make your custom validator function this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847862/min-max-validator-in-angular-2-final

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the expected result, use below options of `keyup` event

1. On every key up, slit input value by **'.'**
2. The first part of the split array will have value before the decimal point and the second part of the array will have value after decimal point
3. Reassign input value based on length

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)" />
```

**component.ts**

```
 onKeyup(e) {
    const val = e.target.value.split(".");
    if (!val[1]) {
      e.target.value =
        val[0].split("").length > 2
          ? e.target.value.substr(0, e.target.value.length - 1)
          : e.target.value;
    } else {
      e.target.value =
        val[1].split("").length > 2
          ? val[0] + "." + val[1].substr(0, val[1].length - 1)
          : e.target.value;
    }
  }
```

working code sample for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-p1gh1

Updated code with HTML and javascript

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xoLqdN?editors=1010

```js
function onKeyup(e) {
  const val = e.target.value.split(".");
    if (!val[1]) {
      e.target.value =
        val[0].split("").length > 2
          ? e.target.value.substr(0, e.target.value.length - 1)
          : e.target.value;
    } else {
      e.target.value =
        val[1].split("").length > 2
          ? val[0] + "." + val[1].substr(0, val[1].length - 1)
          : e.target.value;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup ="onKeyup(event)"/>
```