# Hiding arrow from date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I'm trying to hide extra information and arrows from a date input but it is not hiding in Chrome browser, it does hide in IE.

I'm using the following CSS and cannot see any error.

```
input[type=date]:-webkit-datetime-edit,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22306944/1059101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Or you can include a class in HTML for example `.remove--arrow` and try this:

```
.remove--arrow {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.remove--arrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.remove--arrow::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```