# How to change wheel colors in input type=number using CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have looked into multiple articles. Some of them lists about [disappearing/hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107118/how-to-remove-the-arrows-from-inputtype-number-in-opera) the wheels but I wanted to change the color of wheels.

I have tried the following CSS selector, but it didn't work.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button 
{
     color: red;
     background-color: green;
}
```

Any other suggestion for selector to use, to change wheels background color as well arrow colors?

[image: wheel color of number input field]

Comment: I mean you can't change spin's color/background. Hide them, create two new elements and increase/decrease by JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this by using pseudo class.

```css
.number {
  position: relative;
}

.number:after,
.number:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: .9em;
  font-size: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.number:after {
  color: red;
  content: "\25B2";
   width:12px;
  background-color:green;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.number:before {
  color: red;
  width:12px;
  content: "\25BC";
   background-color:green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  bottom: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class='number'>
    <input type="number" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Here first we are applying appearance none to the default spinners.
And then we are adding custom properties to it. Remember to define **width** as it makes sure to display custom spinner since the default one is unused.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button 
{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: red;
    width: 1em;
    border-left: 1px solid #BBB;
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```